# get value through e.target in reac for from mapped forms

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

> I am displaying multiple forms by mapping in react, and submit button
>   is in parent component, how to getvalues of all the forms which are
>   mapped on form submit?
>
> below is my code for parent component:

```
<form>
     {rowdata.map((item, index) => <ChildForm key={index} {...this.state} />)}
     <Button type="submit" className="primarybtn btnsmall"/>
         </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the entire form inside a the component and simply map the component with the form and button inside of it.

Just pass props down.

Parent Component.

```
return (
{someArray.map(form => (
     <SomeForm onSubmit={this.formSubmitHandler} key={form.key} />

)}
```

Child Component.

```
import React from 'react;

function SomeForm(props) {
return (
<div>
 <form onSubmit={props.onSubmitHandler}>
   Your Form Here
   <Button type="submit" className="primarybtn btnsmall"/>
</form>
 )}
```

Comment: what if button exists in parent,. By your method, each form will have a button

Comment: You want to put a form in a form?

Comment: Putting forms inside of forms wont work. You can maybe put the button inside a div and use state to control the amount of forms you want to appear with each click.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using forms inside of forms.
Maybe you should use different input modes and a single button to submit the input values.
For getting the values you can construct a array of objects( one object for one Iteration the map function)

Comment: i have a default form in parent and mapping is working based on a button. If i click that button new forms keep appending to default form